# AWS Checks for Lambda functions that are configured to use a runtime that is approaching deprecation or is deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I receive the following warning from AWS, but I don't know how to fix this problem.
My understanding, I'll have to upgrade my local computer Node version to version 14, then re-build my application and push up again to AWS.

```
Description: Checks for Lambda functions that are configured to use a runtime that is approaching deprecation or is deprecated. Deprecated runtimes are not eligible for security updates or technical support.
```

My question, do I have to rebuild my application using Node version 14 or something simple like change the runtime version in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

It is not about local build. Each lambda has a language environment. Change your lambda environment/setting/config.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the warning message is referring to the runtime is deprecated or about to deprecate.  Some of the function is in Node 8 and Node 10.  I assume the Node version need to change to a higher version.  If the Node version is change, then the function need to test its compatibility with the new Node version.

Comment: Ok then, what's your point? I think you know answers already. 1) Test compatibility or 2) Read migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to the node version that your Lambda function is running on. Depending how you created it (e.g. with aws cdk, cloudformation, or just in the console) will decide how you can update it.

Updating the "runtime" property of the lambda to a newer Node version for your function should resolve the error.

More information on Lambda runtimes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html